# Alternatives to tracking queries of table rows than a "count" row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I need to keep track of the number of times each row in a table is queried. I need to do this over many tables.

One idea is the "search_count" column

```
id  | other data ...  | search_count
 1  |      ...        |       12
 2  |      ...        |       90
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this than to have a "search count" column? I know this would work but its giving me a bad "code smell" because I would have to do an update after every query (Or a trigger?). We'll use Piwik or Google Analytics as much as possible but they wouldn't be completely accurate because we have more than just the web server interfacing the database.

That database is MySQL 5.x

Thanks

Comment: There's literally no way to prevent an update or insert from occurring per instance of this - it just depends on where you write to, and whether or not it is buffered. At best, you could cache such information before committing it to the database in your app's data layer, but analyzing the queries before they go out -- but that is likely to be very error-prone. It boils down to this: If you need to record information upon each select, then there's no reason to feel bad about writing data each select. Also consider a @Debug flag that turns writing/updating off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this in the DB on the fly would generate far too many dead rows...

Track this using `memcache->increment` in your favorite language. It is atomic. And use a cron to store the results daily or hourly.

Pseudo-code to count:

```
$ns = $memcache->get('count_ns');
$memcache->increment("count-$ns-$table-$id");
```

On cron:

```
$ns = $memcache->get('count_ns');
sleep(1); // allow processes to finish
$memcache->increment('count_ns');
while ($row = $rows->next()) {
  if ($count = $memcache->get("count-$ns-$table-$id") {
    // increment count
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I think I will give this a try. Thanks